# Can I claim that a hot dip Aluminum coating in steel provides cathodic protection to a substrate since Al can act as sacrificial anode?

Tags: electrochemistry

I have a school experiment wherein I will put aluminum coating to a steel substrate, wherein the Al will act as a corrosion protector for the steel. We know that aluminum is also classified as a sacrificial anode. Can the aluminum coating on the steel provides a cathodic protection?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange. Have a look at the FAQ to learn how to post good questions, and hopefully get good answers. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, no -- at least, not at ambient temperature.  Aluminum passivates and this passive film breaks the potential electrochemical circuit.  The passivated aluminum can't react to release electrons to the steel.  For cathodic protection you need something that will corrode instead of the steel, meaning it can't passivate.

Usually, cathodic protection is offered by zinc which has less driving force, but it does not passivate and thus the electrochemical circuit remains intact.

Addendum:

Aluminizing does offer cathodic protection at **high temperature** where the passivation is less effective.

Comment: So the corrosion protection that Al coating provides for steels cannot be considered a cathodic protection?

Comment: That is right, at least under ambient conditions.  Aluminizing is more effective at high temperature where the aluminum finally becomes more reactive.  See http://www.onealsteel.com/carbon-steel-sheet-aluminized.html.

Comment: I have read about this concept. So if the aluminum coating on steel passivates, it can provide great corrosion protection for the steel, although this process can't be considered cathodic protection, right?

Comment: Not cathodic protection, right.